# insert to database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I wonder why this code is not working :

```
public function syarat_post()
{
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $jml_syarat = $this->post('jmlsyarat');
    $i = 0;
    while($i < $jml_syarat){
        $syarat_pendaftaran = array(
            "tmpermohonan_id" => $this->post("idpendaf"),
            "trsyarat_perizinan_id" => $this->post("syarat$i")
        );
        $this->db->insert('tmpermohonan_trsyarat_perizinan', $syarat_pendaftaran);
        $i++;
    }
    $this->db->trans_complete();
}
```

And here is the post :

```
jmlsyarat=4&syarat0=16&syarat1=31&syarat2=190&syarat3=61&idpendaf=8970
```

That is created by this function that using curl for execution :

```
private function syarat($syarat){
    $base_url_websevices = Settings::get('perizinan_online_webservice');
    $this->load->library('curl');
    $this->load->library('xml_parsing_win');
    //$jmlsyarat = $syarat['jmlsyarat'];
    $syaratxml = "";
    $x = 0;
    while($x < $syarat['jmlsyarat']){
        $syaratxml .= "&syarat".$x."=".$syarat['syarat'][$x];
        $x++;
    } 
    $xml = "jmlsyarat=".$syarat['jmlsyarat'].$syaratxml."&idpendaf=".$syarat['idpendaf'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$base_url_websevices/api/syarat/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Finally, it is not writing to database

Comment: Are you getting correct data in `$syarat_pendaftaran` pls make sure

Comment: @pradeep yes, I am getting correct data, even if I make it static. It is not writing to database. I confuse why it is not writing to database

Comment: make sure table and fields name are correct see your logs for error

Comment: table and fields is correct. I still confuse why it is not working

Comment: as per code it seems that you are using transaction functionality( trans_start,trans_complete). due to some error  Transactions prevent to enter record into database. did you check it without using Transactions  statements ?

Comment: Yes i already check it too... removing it, and change it to query still not working...

Comment: may be some parsing error of post  see this :https://eval.in/1021486

Comment: From post are you getting this string `jmlsyarat=4&syarat0=16&syarat1=31&syarat2=190&syarat3=61&idpendaf=8970`